# Eclipse: export java library with dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to export a java library in eclipse that has other dependencies - namely apache commons-io. I was able to export it by going to `Export >> Jar File` - making sure that the libraries are ticked in the "Select the resources to export" box. However, when I implement the library into a test class and run it; I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils
    at com.jwf.JavaWebFramework.main.PageBuilder.copyInputFiles(PageBuilder.java:135)
    at com.jwf.JavaWebFramework.main.PageBuilder.build(PageBuilder.java:44)
    at com.jwf.JavaWebFramework.main.JWF.init(JWF.java:18)
    at com.jwf.JWFTest.JWFTest2Main.main(JWFTest2Main.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
```

For whatever reason, Eclipse doesn't appear to be finding the FileUtils class.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: don't bake them into the package... these should be referenced in the `.pom`.

Comment: Does the exported JAR file contain `org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.class`? How do you start it? Do you use JPMS?

Comment: @Martin Apologies for the late reply, I have tried adding the following code to the pom.xml file
`<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
 </dependency>
  </dependencies>`

Unfortunately, I am still getting the same error. Was this what you were referring to or something else?

Thank you for your support.

Comment: @howlger Previously, the jar file didn't appear to have the `org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.class` file - just the commons-io jar file. However, after building with Maven *see previous comment to Martin*, this file was no longer included.